# Android real time pixel color

Tags: android, arduino

i have RGB Led lights and i need to capture android screen in 100x1 pixels for one line of LEDs, then i send this to arduino and he is show me android pixel colors in LED line.
Ok, how to get android screenshot 30 times of second (like video but in 100x1 resolution) there is the question.

1 LED light gona be one pixel color from screen, how to get real time screen colors in 100x1 resolution?